# Get number of bad lines/errors while reading csv with pandas ( error_bad_lines)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am reading a csv file in pandas, and I am skipping some bad lines / rows with:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", sep=';', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)
```

How can I count the total number of skipped rows in python?

Right now, I only get:
[image]

How can I count this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could calculate the row difference:

```
with open("test.csv") as f:
    len_csv = sum(1 for line in f)

number_of_skipped_rows = len_csv - len(df2)
```

Comment: Check to make sure your data doesn't have a header, or this could introduce an off-by-one error

Answer (score 2):

```
f = open("Test.csv")
row_count= len(f.readlines())
df2 = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", sep=';', engine='python', error_bad_lines=False)
```

Count of skipped rows

```
skipped_rows  = row_count  - df2.shape[0]
```

Comment: this is not working, the command `df1 = pd.read_csv("Test.csv", sep=';', engine='python')`, while give an error.

Comment: name csv is not definied

Comment: now it is working, but I must say, I do not need to import another library, so right now, I prefer Carsten solution

Comment: now its quite simliar, but the code is also the same approach